# Using parameters to set background in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, parameters

I want to set a background for a div with react js by giving the background url as a parameter. Can anyone help me out?

this is the main function

```js
function Main (){
    return (
        <main className="Main">
            <List BGimage={"./20180820_192057.jpg"}/>
        </main>
    )
}

// and I want tp give BGimage as a paramater to set my background image

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class List extends Component{
        render() 

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div ClassName="BackGround" style={{backgroundImage: this.props.BGimage}}>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default List
```

Answer (score 2):

your code is fine, but you just must add url, like in css

```
return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div ClassName="BackGround" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.BGimage})`}}>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Im sorry, i don’t speak English very well, I hope helpful